# How do i make sure that multiple PeriodicWorkRequests are not generated?

Tags: java, android, service, android-workmanager

So I wanted to use a PeriodicWorkRequest to download some data in the background every 15 min or so. But my periodicWorkRequest gets created in the onCreate method and everytime I open the app, a new request gets created. Any way I can make sure only one of these requests are generated?

And I did not paste the code as I thought my description above should be enough.

Comment: There are various ways to solve this, the easiest being persistence. On initial work request, persist the model on the device. Then on next app startup, manage that persisted model if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use **WorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork()**.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest)